# Enunciate with SpringMVC Annotation-based configuration

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, enunciate

I am trying to use Enunciate to generate static documentation for my REST API that is written in Java using Spring MVC 3.2. The Enunciate website claims that it has Spring support by using a specific plugin here :

http://enunciate.codehaus.org/module_spring_app.html

When looking at the configuration options, it looks like I am supposed to import a spring applicationContext.xml. I use the annotation-based configuration for this project, so I don't have an applicationContext.xml. Is there a way to make this work in my case?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Enunciate currently supports Spring Web annotations.

Comment: this is not true any more in 2018. There is a spring module now: https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/wiki/Module-Spring-Web . However, I am still struggling to make it work with my SpringBoot app, so not sure how compatible it is.

Comment: It should be working find with Spring Boot. We've got a number of successfully documented applications running on Spring boot.

Comment: I'm adding Enunciate to a Web Services application made with Spring Boot: can you link some examples?

Comment: There's currently no support for Spring Web Services; just Spring Web (REST) annotations.